# Hyper-V: Isolate I/O input of vm from the host

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, hyper-v, hypervisor

Is it possible to use a VM in parallel with the host, simultaneously, by two different users on the same physical machine?

I got to the point where I have a working VM with Windows 10(the host also uses windows 10). I want to use two sets of mice & keyboards separately, one on the VM and another on the host.

Is it possible to assign a usb port only to the VM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no possibility to attach an USB device separately to a VM in Hyper-v as per my knowledge.